# Leaflet (OSM tiles) Shown as a ground plane in a 2D environment

Tags: javascript, three.js, leaflet

I'd like to take a tile, which I'm pulling from Openstreetmaps and making it the ground plane for a 3D environment.  I've looked into three.js which looks promising, but I feel I'm making this problem a little more complicated than it needs to be.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([46.742798, -116.988537], 18);

var tile = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3'

}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker( [ 46.742798, -116.988537 ] ).addTo( map )
        .bindPopup("<b> Hello World</b><br />").openPopup();


var popup = L.popup();

var ll = L.latLng( 46.742798, -116.988537 );
var polyline = L.polyline( ll, { color: 'green' } ).addTo( map );

var dragSwitch = false;

function onMapClick( e )
{
    popup
        .setLatLng( e.latlng )
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn( map );
}


try
{
    object.new_coord.connect( fnc );
}
catch ( e )
{
    print( e );
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

So, taking the map variable in the code above and having that be the ground plane.  Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't support 3D, and trying to make it support 3D would be more work than it's worth. There are other systems that support 3D already, like [WebGL earth](http://www.webglearth.com/#ll=38.89510,-77.03640;alt=7000000) and [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/), which you should start with.

Comment: Thanks for the response tmcw.  I don't want the leaflet image to be 3D.  I just want the 2D vector tile as my ground plane.

Comment: Your question says "I'd like to visualize leaflet maps in 3D fashion." - please be way more specific about what you want, because it's very difficult to understand.